# Optaplanner Score corruption

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner, drools-planner, drools-kie-server

I'm working on a problem that's similar to vehicle routing problem and I have a rule to avoid multiple employees using same vehicle same time. Also, I'm using multi level bendable score just for verbose score calculation.
With this rule
I have enabled FAST_ASSERT and with this I incur with below exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Impossible VariableListener corruption: the expectedWorkingScore
(-788init/[0/0/-10/-20/-3/0/-12/-788/0/0]hard/[0/0/-25/-75/0]soft) is not the workingScore 
(-788init/[0/0/-10/-60/-3/0/-12/-788/0/0]hard/[0/0/-25/-75/0]soft) after all VariableListeners were triggered without changes to the genuine variables.
But all the shadow variable values are still the same, so this is impossible.
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.assertShadowVariablesAreNotStale(AbstractScoreDirector.java:472)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.scope.DefaultSolverScope.assertShadowVariablesAreNotStale(DefaultSolverScope.java:140)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.scope.AbstractPhaseScope.assertShadowVariablesAreNotStale(AbstractPhaseScope.java:171)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.AbstractPhase.predictWorkingStepScore(AbstractPhase.java:169)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.doStep(DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.java:108)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.solve(DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.java:95)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:87)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:167)
```

In AbstractScoreDirector, I looked at move type and it's ChainedChangeMove and it's toString looks like:

```
T:1568135-2-10- {T:1656844-2-10- -> T:1656844-2-10-}
```

which surprises me as it's trying to assign same chain to entity as it has previously(1656844 being first entity in chain).

A.Need help understanding above exception so I can work on fixing it.

B.How can we make sure move creator do not create useless moves ie assigning same fact to entity as it has previously, just like above?

**Updated FULL_ASSERT exception:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Score corruption: the workingScore
([0/0/0/-1440/-602/0/-633/0/0/0]hard/[-120/0/-813/-2946/0]soft) is not the uncorruptedScore
([0/0/0/-1640/-602/0/-633/0/0/0]hard/[-120/0/-813/-2946/0]soft) after completedAction
 (T:1692296-2-5- {T:1690774-2-10- -> T:1690774-2-10-}):
  The corrupted scoreDirector has no ConstraintMatch(s) which are in excess.
  The corrupted scoreDirector has 20 ConstraintMatch(s) which are missing:
    com.kairos.planning.rules/Employees use same vehicle same time/[E:941, E:785]=[0/0/0/-10/0/0/0/0/0/0]hard/[0/0/0/0/0]soft
    com.kairos.planning.rules/Employees use same vehicle same time/[E:941, E:765]=[0/0/0/-10/0/0/0/0/0/0]hard/[0/0/0/0/0]soft
    com.kairos.planning.rules/Employees use same vehicle same time/[E:941, E:809]=[0/0/0/-10/0/0/0/0/0/0]hard/[0/0/0/0/0]soft
    com.kairos.planning.rules/Employees use same vehicle same time/[E:941, E:1049]=[0/0/0/-10/0/0/0/0/0/0]hard/[0/0/0/0/0]soft
    com.kairos.planning.rules/Employees use same vehicle same time/[E:941, E:881]=[0/0/0/-10/0/0/0/0/0/0]hard/[0/0/0/0/0]soft
    com.kairos.planning.rules/Employees use same vehicle same time/[E:941, E:961]=[0/0/0/-10/0/0/0/0/0/0]hard/[0/0/0/0/0]soft
    com.kairos.planning.rules/Employees use same vehicle same time/[E:785, E:941]=[0/0/0/-10/0/0/0/0/0/0]hard/[0/0/0/0/0]soft
    com.kairos.planning.rules/Employees use same vehicle same time/[E:765, E:941]=[0/0/0/-10/0/0/0/0/0/0]hard/[0/0/0/0/0]soft
    ... 12 more
  Check your score constraints.
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.assertWorkingScoreFromScratch(AbstractScoreDirector.java:491)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.scope.DefaultSolverScope.assertWorkingScoreFromScratch(DefaultSolverScope.java:132)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.scope.AbstractPhaseScope.assertWorkingScoreFromScratch(AbstractPhaseScope.java:167)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.LocalSearchDecider.processMove(LocalSearchDecider.java:163)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.LocalSearchDecider.doMove(LocalSearchDecider.java:148)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.LocalSearchDecider.decideNextStep(LocalSearchDecider.java:120)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.solve(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:70)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:87)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:167)
```

Comment: You might not believe it but FAST_ASSERT does not throw any corruption exception. I know it's just coincidence, but I've tried multiple times. but I'll TRACE log and will update my question.

Comment: I had almost the same problem. I've switched from FAST_ASSERT to FULL_ASSERT and then the error messages pointed to issues with a variable listener that were corrupting the working solution. I've removed the listener logic and moved it to my domain logic and the error doesn't happen any more.